# Copy values from one sheet into another using Filter option

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the values from one Excel sheet into another using Filter option. For example I have used only ten records, but in real time I am not sure the data that will be present. Also, I need to know the first cell value after a filter. For example, if I use filter the first value is reflecting as B4 and next time it is showing B6. I need to select that also dynamically using macro.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BG$10").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="2"
Range("B5:BG5").Select
```

The above code should be modified. Instead of $BG$10 it should be the number of rows, then Instead of B5:BG5 it must be the first cell after filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastRow As Long, firstVisibleRow As Long

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    'find last non empty row number in column A'
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'apply filter'
    Range("$A$1:$BG$" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="2"

    On Error GoTo errHandler
    'find first visible row number in the filtered range, if there is no rows matching the filter criteria, we'll get message from the MsgBox'
    firstVisibleRow = Range("$A$2:$BG$" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
    'select range'
    Range("B" & firstVisibleRow & ":BG" & firstVisibleRow).Select

    Exit Sub
errHandler:
        MsgBox "There is no rows matching the filter criteria"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim rngToFilter As Range

With ActiveSheet
     .AutoFilterMode = False 'to make sure no filter is applied yet
     Set rngToFilter = .Range("A1", .Range("BG" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'set the dynamic range
     rngToFilter.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="2" 'apply the filter
     rngToFilter.Resize(.Range("BG" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select 'Offset 1 row to exclude the header, resize to select the first row only.
End With
```

Above code selects all the items that are filtered.
I you want so select only the 1st item filtered, then use below.

```
Sub Sample()

Dim rngToFilter As Range, rngFilter As Range
Dim i As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False 'to make sure no filter is applied yet
    Set rngToFilter = .Range("A1", .Range("BG" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'set the dynamic range
    rngToFilter.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="2" 'apply the filter
    Set rngFilter = rngToFilter.Resize(.Range("BG" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1).Offset(1, _
                        0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rngToFilter.Resize(.Range("BG" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - _
                    (rngFilter.Cells.Count / rngFilter.Columns.Count)).Offset(1, _
                        0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
End With

End Sub
```

No error handler yet.
I leave it to you. :D

Comment: First one, but it throws me an error for the large number of values. I need another help, how to specify multiple filter values

Comment: what dyou mean large number of values? :D Btw, you can filter multiple items like this: `Criteria1:=Array("2","3","4","5"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`.